# SSIS - OData Connection to Sharepoint List Failed Validation Error 0xC020801F

Tags: ssis

In SSIS (version 15, created through Visual Studio 2017), I am trying to connect to a Sharepoint list ("Deficiencies") with an HTTPS URL. I get this error:

Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC020801F at Data Flow Task, OData Source [2]: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the run-time connection manager.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: OData Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801F.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "C:\Users\richard.ocarroll\OneDrive - GXO\SSIS\Backhaul data\Backhaul data\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[13868] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It works in preview and the test connection works

I also did the below

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:64

Was hoping to pull the data to a data warehouse but keeps failing